# How to select training samples by number in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I now have 100 training data, and I want to randomly select 50 training data. How can I use Google Earth Engine to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use randomColumn() to give each feature a random value, then filter the collection to keep some percentage.

```
subset = collection.randomColumn().filter("random < 0.5")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using `randomColumn` and `filter` is not enough to select exactly 50 from 100 elements. I'm not sure how your data is stored, but if it is a Image Collection or Feature Collection, you can do the following:

```
// example of Image Collection (with 10 elements just for ilustration)
var IC = ee.ImageCollection([ee.Image(1),ee.Image(2),ee.Image(3),ee.Image(4),ee.Image(5),
                             ee.Image(6),ee.Image(7),ee.Image(8),ee.Image(9),ee.Image(10)]);
print(IC)

// add a random property with values between 0 and 1 for each Image/Feature
IC = IC.randomColumn('random')
print(IC)

// 50% percentile of the random property
var p50 = IC.aggregate_array('random').reduce(ee.Reducer.percentile([50]))
print(p50)

// select randomly 50% of the data in your Collection
print(IC.filterMetadata('random', 'less_than',p50))
```

And if it is not in a collection, maybe you can "force it" to be stored that way using `ee.ImageCollection` or `ee.FeatureCollection`. A bit late but hope it works for future uses!